# React Native functional component constructor

Tags: react-native

How can convert **Class Component** *constructor* to **Functional Component**?

> FROM CLASS COMPONENT

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
      this.state = {
       myText: 'I\'m ready to get swiped!',
       gestureName: 'none',
       backgroundColor: '#fff'
      };
    }
```

> TO FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT

```
const Component = () => {
//CODE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change your class to functions you must know what is `hooks`: so what is a `hooks`?: They let you use state and other React features without writing a class.

to define the state you will use `useState` function(useState it one kooks)

so your factional component will look like the following:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
const Component = () => {
  const [myText, setMyText] = useState('I\'m ready to get swiped!');
  const [gestureName, setGestureName] = useState('none');
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('#fff');

  return ....
}
```

To learn more about functionals component and their hooks check their doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html